# TapgestureRecogniser detecting touch as Scrollview

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiscrollview, xcode4.5, uitapgesturerecognizer

Im adding a UIPickerView to a scrollview.When I went through selecting a row from pickerview it gets hidden and I couldnot select it because I have written code to remove pickerview when user taps anywhere on the screen(scrollView) other than pickerView.But now even I tap(select) pickerview I m gtng pickerview hidden because touch is deted as ScrollView.I couldn't understand where Im going wrong.

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch{

    if(touch.view==testScroll)
    {

        if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
        {
            ViewForValuePicker.hidden=true;//view to which pickerview is added and this s view is added to scrollview
            pickerView.hidden=YES;

        }
        return YES; 
    } 
   else

        return NO; 
}
```

What can I do to remove pickerview when clicked anywhere on the screen and dont remove it when tapped on row of pickerview

Answer (score 0):

try like this may be it helps you,

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event  {
    NSLog(@"touches began");
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];   
    if([touch view] isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]){

    //do whatever you want to do  here

   }
}
```

Comment: But this method is not getting called.Can u tell me what to do?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to create a second gesture recognizer for the pickerview which swallows those taps which shouldn't be sent to scrollview.

Pls see for illustration a complete test project to achieve this. You can see that tapping the pickerview was routed to the *gestureswallover* method and the outside of the pickerview all taps were routed to *gesturehelper* method so you can implement your logic in these methods.

in ViewController.h these are the gesture recognizers' action methods:

```
- (IBAction) gesturehelper: (UITapGestureRecognizer*) sender;
- (IBAction) gestureswallover: (UITapGestureRecognizer*) sender;
```

[image]

In my ViewController.m I have this (specific logic should be included in action methods):

```
- (IBAction) gesturehelper: (UITapGestureRecognizer*) sender {
    NSLog(@"gesturehelper tap, %@", sender.view);
}
- (IBAction) gestureswallover: (UITapGestureRecognizer*) sender {
    NSLog(@"gestureswallover tap, %@", sender.view);    
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return 5;
}
```